In Emacs lsp-mode, is there a way to modify function signature?
In lsp-mode (or any other Emacs cases), I can use lsp-rename to rename a var/id, all references being updated automatically. Now I want to modify a function's signature, e.g. adding an argument, in a way similar lsp-rename. Anyone knows how to to that, thanks.

Offhand it does not seem to be possible in general. While searching, the only similar question I see is this one for Neovim and there similarly no answers. I tried digging into LSP protocol to see whether it's technically possible, but from the cursory look haven't found an answer. I'd presume if it was possible it would be something to do with textDocument/codeAction. If you want you might try digging further into it.
